# Adding the values of form elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, sum

I'm having a difficulty adding form elements together. If you could check out my code and fill me in on what I'm doing wrong, I'd greatly appreciate it. Here is a jsFiddle link of the code also: http://jsfiddle.net/jaruesink/6Z6hz/1/embedded/result/

```
<html><head><script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js">
</script></head><body>
<h1>How Much?</h1>  
<form id="quickcalc">
Softcover Only<br>
<select id="SoftcoverOnly">
    <option value="0" selected>Select Package</option>
    <option value="360">Level A ($360)</option>
    <option value="440">Level B ($440)</option>
    <option value="495">Level C ($495)</option>
    <option value="790">Level D ($790)</option>
    <option value="1100">Level E ($1,110)</option>
    <option value="1390">Level F ($1,390)</option>
    <option value="1950">Level G ($1,950)</option>
</select><br><br>
Hardcover Only<br>
<select id="HardcoverOnly">
    <option value="0" selected>Select Package</option>
    <option value="430">Level A ($430)</option>
    <option value="495">Level B ($495)</option>
    <option value="650">Level C ($650)</option>
    <option value="950">Level D ($950)</option>
    <option value="1300">Level E ($1,300)</option>
    <option value="1575">Level F ($1,575)</option>
    <option value="2100">Level G ($2,100)</option>
</select><br><br>
Combo Hard/Soft<br>
<select id="ComboHard/Soft">
    <option value="0" selected>Select Package</option>
    <option value="590">Level A ($590)</option>
    <option value="685">Level B ($685)</option>
    <option value="825">Level C ($825)</option>
    <option value="1050">Level D ($1,050)</option>
    <option value="1375">Level E ($1,375)</option>
    <option value="1650">Level F ($1,650)</option>
    <option value="2225">Level G ($2,225)</option>
</select><br><br>
Additional Services<br>
<select id="AdditionalServices" multiple size="3">
    <option value="0" disabled>Ctrl+Click for Multiple</option>
    <option value="100">Warehouseing ($100)</option>
    <option value="75">Amazon Backup ($75)</option>
    <option value="250">PR Writing ($250)</option>
    <option value="75">Ingram Advance ($75)</option>
    <option value="30">TOC Creation ($30)</option>
    <option value="75">Index Creation ($75)</option>
    <option value="50">Printed Galley ($50)</option>
    <option value="65">Ebook Package ($65)</option>
    <option value="30">Casebinding ($30)</option>
    <option value="40">Dustjacket ($40)</option>
</select><br><br>
Marketing Packages<br>
<select id="MarketingPackages">
    <option value="0" selected>Select Package</option>
    <option value="400">Bronze ($400)</option>
    <option value="700">Silver ($700)</option>
    <option value="1300">Gold ($1300)</option>
</select><br><br>
Your Total:<br>
<input type="text" readonly id="totalPrice" value="">
</form>
  <div></div>
 <script>
$("#quickcalc").change(function () {
      var total = "";
      $("#quickcalc option:selected").each(
            function(){total += parseInt($(this).val())}
      );  
      $("#totalPrice").val("$"+total);
}).change();
 </script>

 </body></html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try var total = 0;
instead of var total = "";

You must have an integer, but you now have a string!

Answer (score 4):

Try starting off with `var total = 0;`

http://jsfiddle.net/6Z6hz/2/

Answer (score 1):

You're still concatenating strings. Change `total="";` to `total=0;`